# http.post on Angular5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular4-forms

Angular 5
I am trying to build a function that create a resource on my API using Angular. 
On my employee.service.ts file I have a method called "saveEmployee" which is called by a function "addEmployee" which is on Employee.componenet.ts The function "addEmployee" is called when "Save Employee" button is pressed on HTML page.
This is addEmployee function:

```
 addEmployee(model) {
this.loading = true;
model.contractorId = parseInt(model.contractorId);
this.employeeService.saveEmployee(model)
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log('saved successfully!!!');
      return true;
    },
    error => {
      console.error("Error creating employee!");
      return Observable.throw(error);
      });
}
```

And this is saveEmployee:

```
 saveEmployee(employee: Employee): Observable<Employee> {

let body = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(employee));
return this.http.post(this.resourceUrl, body);
}
```

It is failing because of "invalid media type" because for some reason the JSON object pushed to the API has this look:

```
{  
  firstName:"arjan",
  lastName:"gjoni",
  fedexId:"7777",
  contractorId:20
}
```

If you notice this is not a valid JSON object because the property names are not in quotes.

I placed a console.log() on the saveEmployee function after Json.stringify() and the Jason object is valid in there. I also placed a console.log() on the addEmployee() function and there the JSON object is weird (like the one on the post). 
I also checked on console, the RequestPayload and in there the JSON object is not valid either.

I would appreciate any help. I am using Angular 5

Comment: How your employee looks like before, let body = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(employee)); ?

Comment: Can you post the other headers being sent to the server from the browser? Have you been able to get any call to the API endpoint run successfully using postman or something similar? I think the object looks fine but you might have to add a media type to your header.

Comment: with post man works only if I put on quotes all the property names ("firstName", "lastName", "fedexId", "contractorId")

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the `employee` object as the second parameter of the `this.http.post` method instead of stringifying and parsing it into the body object.
Angular should be able to handle the native Javascript object and post it correctly to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let body = JSON.stringify(employee);
return this.http.post(this.resourceUrl, body);
```

Comment: This. You should explain why. He needs to stringinfy the JSON object so that it is proper JSON syntax, as opposed to simply a JavaScript object which is what he's currently sending.

Comment: It is not working. Same error. I placed a console.log on the saveEmployee function after Json.stringify() and the Jason object is valid in there. I also placed a console.log on the addEmployee() function and there the JSON object is weird (like the one on the post). 
I also checked on console, the RequestPayload and in there the JSON object is not valid either.

Comment: @Lansana when I console.log() the object passed on the method before JSON.stringify() it only displays [object Object]

Comment: your employee has a problem, because this code is correct for send data to api